# How to fix multiple-value stmt.Query() in single-value context

Tags: postgresql, go, golang-migrate

I am facing the above issue with the code below

```
    stmt, err2 := db.Prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  xyz WHERE product_id=? and chart_number=?")
    rows, err2 := stmt.Query( bidStatusReqVal.ProductId,bidStatusReqVal.ChartNumber).Scan(&count)
```

Comment: `Query().Scan()` ain't valid. Call `Scan` on the returned `rows`, or use `QueryRow().Scan()` with only `err` as the return destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Query(...).Scan(...)` is not valid because `Query` returns *two* values and chaining of calls requires that the previous call returns only *one* value. Call `Scan` on the returned `rows`, or use `QueryRow(...).Scan(...)` with only `err` as the return destination.

```golang
rows, err := stmt.Query(bidStatusReqVal.ProductId, bidStatusReqVal.ChartNumber)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    if err := rows.Scan(&count); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    return err
}

// ...
```

In cases where the query returns only a single row, e.g. `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`, or `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` like in your case, it is much more convenient to use `QueryRow`.

```golang
err := stmt.QueryRow(bidStatusReqVal.ProductId, bidStatusReqVal.ChartNumber).Scan(&count)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// ...
```